# JS - Proxy a CORS Request under the users IP Address?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, cors

Is it possible to create a Proxy perhaps (ip:port) with `NodeJS?` to bypass CORS issues?

For example, make a proxy that when connected, all responses returned when using the proxy would return `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {domain}` header?

If so, where would I go to achieve this?

Why am I looking to do this?
Im trying to essentially be able to bind events to a video tag for an external iframe embed page (Not YouTube so API wont help here).
But of course, CORS as usual stops me from having fun, grr.
Whats annoying too is that, the embed page binds through IP Address, if it didnt, a simple file_get_contents would have worked with a simple PHP page with GET params.

Answer (score 0):

I would use nginx proxy server for that.

Eventually, it will bring you more effort, not only proxying requests.

To resolve CORS issue, you can use [cors npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) in your express apps, for example, or simply adding so-known [CORS headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

Comment: Would using that npm module work with Electron, and does it actually use the requesters IP address and not the servers IP?

Comment: This module simply adds request headers. It's done on the server side. The electron app is - client side, right?